# Setting a locale for an ajax request in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, autocomplete, internationalization, locale

I'm wondering is there an elegant way to **pass a locale in an ajax** request. I have an autocopmlete field, which should take only the values for the given language.

The coffeescript is like:

```
  ...
  $('#post_name').autocomplete
        source: "/ajax/posts"
  ...
```

I'd like the source to be like: "/en/ajax/posts" or "/he/ajax/posts" or whatever.

Sure I can keep a variable in session, or even (worse) pass it through a hidden input.

Please suggest?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can rename your file to coffee.erb so it will be processed by ruby before coffee  (enclose your ruby code with <% %>

Comment: You're welcome.  I18n-js is an other subject, you must create a new question on stackoverflow

Comment: best practice remains to add the proper url in a data field in your dom.

Comment: the only problem as it looks - that the .js.cofee.erb file is being processed only once, because it's in the assets.... :)

Answer (score 0):

After a pinch of thought, it's not a good solution to write the locale and generate the **js** on every request. I'm trying to think about @apneadiving suggestion

Comment: I am facing the same problem and I wonder what @apneadiving's solution would look like. Can anybody specify?

Comment: it means you should add the prefix inside the javascript contidionally. like instead of source: "/ajax/posts"  do source: "/en/ajax/posts" or other language prefix, it's erb right?

Comment: OK, got it thanks. But how can I get the locale dynamically, so I won't have to hardcode it in there?